# Чем опасен выход за границы массива?

Tags: c++, массивы

Можно ли оставлять выход за границы массива в программах? Чем это грозит? Что происходит при выходе за его границы?

Comment: коротко - оставлять нельзя.  чем грозит - чем угодно. UB оно такое)

Comment: Вы можете, например, отредактировать другую переменную, которая лежит вне границах массива.

Comment: Это логическая ошибка,  вы получите неопределенный результат (неизвестно что там записано),  и если используете этот результат, то  дальше программа станет неуправляемой, что и называется неопределенным поведением(UB).

Comment: Зависит от того, как вы написали программу. В общем случае даже чтение может привести к падению программы (SIGBUS или SIGSEGV в *nix (впрочем, можно контролируемо обрабатывать и эти ситуации)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

В современных операционных системах память каждого процесса существует отдельно от других процессов. Программа не может просто так получить доступ к памяти чужого процесса. Проверка осуществляется операционной системой, причём поддержка этого реализована аппаратно в современных процессорах. Это сделано для защиты, чтобы неправильно работающая программа не могла нарушить работу других.

---

Представим память следующим образом:

```
|___память_вашей_программы___массив|___память_чужой_программы___|
```

В данном случае массив расположен в конце области памяти вашей программы. Если произойдёт выход за границу массива, то получится обращение к области памяти чужой программы. Операционная система этого не позволит, произойдёт исключение.

---

А что если массив расположен так:

```
|___сегмент_данных___массив\сегмент_кода___|
```

В каждой программе есть сегмент(ы) кода и сегмент(ы) данных. На уровне операционной системы разным сегментам разрешены разные действия: чтение, запись, исполнение. Это, опять-таки, сделано для обеспечения надёжности. В сегмент кода запись *запрещена*. Соответственно, и в данном случае, если произойдёт обращение за пределами массива, тоже будет выброшено исключение.

---

Третий вариант:

```
|___сегмент_данных___массив___сегмент_данных___|
```

В этом случае выход за пределы массивы не приведёт к исключению, операционная система не может отследить его своими силами, т. к. процесс имеет полное право писать в свой сегмент данных. Просто при этом будут либо прочитаны данные, не относящиеся к массиву, либо повреждены (переписаны) эти данные.

Comment: Ну, наверное лучше этого ответа и не получите нигде

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не ожидал получить такой ответ. Теперь все ясно.

Comment: В первом пункте из-за виртуальной адресации не будет "памяти другой программы". Там будет просто невалидный адрес.