# Является ли способ приведенный в тексте кода динамическим выделением памяти?Если нет,то почему код работает и почему это не динамическое выделение?

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int lenarr = 0;//фактическая длина массива
    int chislo ;
    int size = 1;
    int* arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Введите элемент массива: ";
        cin >> chislo;
        if (chislo == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else if (chislo != 0) {
            arr[i] = chislo;//инициализация массива
            lenarr++;// считаем длину массива
            if (size == lenarr) {
                size = size * 2;//увелчиваем длину нашего
динамического массива
                cout << "Новый размер массива = " << size << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Массив чисел: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < lenarr; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";//вывод массива
    }
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: Да, `new` = динамическое. Почему вы сомневаетесь?

Comment: `size = size * 2` — это никак не увеличение массива. Грубо говоря, от увеличения размера кошелька денег в нем не прибавится...

Comment: Вообще этот код должен не в свою память залезть. Вопрос только когда это произойдёт.

Comment: Этот код работает потому что программа простая и у компьютера очень много памяти. Оператор `size = size * 2` не меняет размер выделенного массива (а было бы удобно, конечно). Начиная со второго элемента вы пишите данные в невыделенную память, сокрушая все структуры менеджера памяти.

Comment: Почему код работает: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/921886/184217 - третий вариант.

Comment: Эта программа работает, но с небольшими но... вы пытаетесь использовать больше памяти чем вам дали, в некоторых средах delete вызовет ошибку "память повреждена", а в некоторых нет. Так как менеджер памяти почти не задействован - то нечему ломаться. Примени это в большом проэкте - большая программа начнёт сыпаться ошибками в других местах, если это работа в команде - вас сочтут саботажником)))) Лучше не приучать себя писать плохо, лучше сразу писать чисто.

Comment: 64-битная среда вообще позволяет очень много памяти выделить. Единственное ограничение - нельзя затирать памяти за границами выделеного. Следуйте этому правилу - и проблем не будет.

Comment: Увеличивая size  вы не увеличиваете себе память. Поэтому у вас динамическое выделение только на старте. А дальше нету выделения памяти, поэтому похожая программа даст рано ли поздно сбой, при чем такой, что ошибка будет найдена не сразу. Для увеличения памяти нужно делать new или вызывать другие функции которые добавляют память.

Answer (score 1):

Держите пример. `capacity` - вместимость массиваа, `size` - сколько элементов в массиве занято, `array` - массив.

Массив увеличивается в два раза, если места не хватает. Выделяется новый массив, данные копируются, стирается старый массив. Это кажется сложным, но проще нельзя, не получается. Удвоение массива нужно чтобы время заполнения массива оставалось минимальным.

`delete [] nullptr;` - "удалять" нулевой указатель можно. Стандарт специально это разрешает.

```
#include <cassert>  
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int capacity = 0; // вместимость массива
    int size = 0;     // сколько места в массиве занято (size <= capacity)
    int *array = nullptr;

    int n;
    while (cin >> n) {
        if (size == capacity) {
            const int new_capacity = (capacity == 0) ? 1 : 2 * capacity;
            assert(new_capacity >= capacity);
            int *new_array = new int[new_capacity];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                new_array[i] = array[i];
            }
            delete [] array;
            array = new_array;
            capacity = new_capacity;
        }
        assert(size < capacity);
        array[size] = n;
        ++size;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            cout << ' ';
        }
        cout << array[i];
    }
    cout << '\n';

    delete[] array;
}
```

Comment: `new_capacity = (capacity == 0) ? ...` это в педагогических целях или `new_capacity = 2 * (capacity + 1);` в самом деле чем-то плохо?

Comment: @avp, в педагогических. В нормальном коде первый шаг был бы 8 или 10 или 16. Универсальное приращение, как у вас, тоже хорошо. Или скажем так: `2 * (capacity + 16)` чтобы увеличить первый шаг.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>

void scan(int*& arr, int& len) {
    std::cout << "length: ";
    std::cin >> len;
    
    if (len <= 0)
        throw std::domain_error("Length must be a positive integer!");
    if (arr != nullptr)
        delete[] arr;
    
    arr = new int[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        std::cout << "--> arr[" << i << "] = ";
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    }
}

void print(const int* arr, int len) {
    std::cout << "[" << arr[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
        std::cout << ", " << arr[i];
    std::cout << "]";
}


int main() {
    int length;
    int* arr = nullptr;
    
    scan(arr, length);
    print(arr, length);
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: у вас переменная `int* arr;` не имеет никакого начального значения, что приводит к ошибке неопределённого поведения программы. А также это не является ответом на вопрос.